# How to loop through contents of scrollable div?

Tags: javascript, html, loops, scroll

So I'm trying to have a `<div>` where the `overflow` is `auto` and so you can scroll through any number of items in that `div`. However, I would like to have it so that when you reach the last item, you see the 1st item again. So that it is an endless loop of the same content.

Is there any simple way to do this with only javascript...

There is possibly another question like this, however the answers are in jquery and to be frank I don't understand how it all works....

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use swiper slider to implement this. There is a ready to use example on the official swiper web site: [example link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/swiper-demo-16-scroll-container?file=index.html)

When you open the code editor by the provided link please add the following changes to the code:

1. Add `loop: true,` on line 98;
2. [Optional] Add more slides to the slider.